# SQL syntax Error while trying to add INT into column inside for loop

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

CURRENT

> ERROR check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Long-Beach/112-E-Eldridge-St-90807/home/7571273' at line 1

new_url prints as `www.redfin.com/CA/Long-Beach/112-E-Eldridge-St-90807/home/7571273` which does show up on my for_sale Table when i search it manually under the filter.

i keep getting a syntax error when i'm trying to add an estimate_price to the row in the current for loop.  I've tried every variation i can think of but still no success. Please advise.  The current value of estimate_price is NULL, the current setting for that field is INT.  Thank You

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT web_url FROM for_sale WHERE estimate_price IS NULL")
for web in mycursor:
    print(web)
    url = str(web)
    new_url = url[10:-3]

    print("NEW URL",new_url)
    
    ## IN PUT IT IN THAT SAME LINE.
    mycursor.execute(f"UPDATE for_sale SET estimate_price = 120000 WHERE web_url = {new_url}")
```

Comment: Can you print/log the whole update command that will be executed?

Comment: You need quotes around `{new_url}` since it's a string.

Comment: But you should use a placeholder and parameters instead of substituting the variable directly into the string.

Comment: Thank You Barmar first time mixing two languages.  I appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar mentions above, you should use a query parameter instead of an f-string. This is the way to do it in Python:

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE for_sale SET estimate_price = 120000 WHERE web_url = %s", [new_url])
```

The Python connector for MySQL will take care of quoting the value and escaping any special characters if necessary. Or if you created the cursor as the [MySQLPreparedCursor subclass](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html), it'll use proper query parameters with PREPARE and EXECUTE, so the value is never combined with the SQL syntax.